# Sorting an array of pointers to struct based on an element inside the struct

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, struct

What i want to do here is to sort an Array of pointers to Structs based on a string inside the Struct .I thought it would be easy to only swapp the pointers inside the array instead of swapping the whole struct . All the Element are dynamically allocated . My code is written in German so i will be writing only the parts that i don't understand in English . thank you in advance I appreciate your help.

```
typedef struct Vehicle {
    char *manufacturer;
    char *serialnumber;
    int weight;
};
void SortByID(struct fahrzeug** data, int Anzahl){ 
    struct Vehicle *temp= (struct Vehicle*)malloc( sizeof(struct Vehicle) );
    int i =0 ;// I think i've written something wrong here ( strcmp)
    while ( i < Anzahl && strcmp(data[i]->serialnumber, data[i+1]->serialnumber) < 0) 
    {
         temp = data[i+1];
         data[i+1] = data[i];
         data[i]=temp ;
         i++;
    }  
    free(temp);
    temp=NULL;
}
int main(){
    int count =0 ;
    struct Vehicle **array = NULL ;
    array=(struct Vehicle**)malloc(  5 * sizeof(struct Vehicle*)  );
    for(int i=0;i<5 ;i++){
       array[i] = (struct Vehicle*)malloc( sizeof(struct Vehicle) ) ;
       count++;
    }
    SortByID (  &array, count ) ; // is this right ?
    return 0; 
}
```

I've also tried to sort it using the qsort function but without success

```
int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
  struct Vehicle * const *one = a;
  struct Vehicle * const *two = b;

  return strcmp((*one)->serialnumber, (*two)->serialnumber);
}
void SortByID(struct Vehicle** data, int Anzahl){
   qsort( data, Anzahl, sizeof(struct Vehicle*) ,compare );
}
```

Comment: You could use [`qsort()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) instead of writing your own sort function.

Comment: thank you i will try it .qsort will only swap the pointers position inside the array ?

Comment: `qsort()` will swap the data in the array, whatever type and size it is. In your case the data is a pointer so that is all that will be swapped as directed by the comparison function.

Comment: will this be ok :  
`int compare ( struct Vehicle*a, struct Vehicle* b){
 return strcmp(a->serialnumber, b->serialnumber);
 
} 
void SortByID(struct fahrzeug** data, int Anzahl){ 
    qsort( data, Anzahl, sizeof(struct fahrzeug*) ,compare );
}`

Comment: Looks right. Try it.

Comment: `Vehicle * const` is not compatible with `const void *a`. The location of the `const` before or after the `*` matters. Constant pointer to data vs pointer to constant data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's a working example using `qsort()`. It can sort by serial number and manufacturer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Vehicle {
    char *manufacturer;
    char *serialnumber;
    int weight;
};

int cmp_serialnumber(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const struct Vehicle *v1 = *(struct Vehicle * const *)p1;
    const struct Vehicle *v2 = *(struct Vehicle * const *)p2;

    return strcmp(v1->serialnumber, v2->serialnumber);

/*
    // Alternatively You could write this function as this less readable one liner
    return strcmp((*(struct Vehicle * const *)p1)->serialnumber,
                    (*(struct Vehicle * const *)p2)->serialnumber);
*/
}

int cmp_manufacturer(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const struct Vehicle *v1 = *(struct Vehicle * const *)p1;
    const struct Vehicle *v2 = *(struct Vehicle * const *)p2;

    return strcmp(v1->manufacturer, v2->manufacturer);
}

void print_vehicles(struct Vehicle **vehicles, int n) {
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%s, %s, %d\n", vehicles[i]->serialnumber,
                vehicles[i]->manufacturer, vehicles[i]->weight);
    }
}


#define N_VEHICLES  5
char *manufacturers[] = {"McLaren", "Ferrari", "Renault", "Mercedes", "Alfa Romeo"};
char *serialnumbers[] = {"SN500", "SN4", "SN8", "SN2", "SN1"};


int main(){
    struct Vehicle **vehicles = NULL;

    vehicles = (struct Vehicle**)malloc(N_VEHICLES * sizeof(struct Vehicle *));

    for(int i=0; i<N_VEHICLES; i++) {
        vehicles[i] = (struct Vehicle *)malloc(sizeof(struct Vehicle));
        vehicles[i]->manufacturer = manufacturers[i];
        vehicles[i]->serialnumber = serialnumbers[i];
        vehicles[i]->weight = 1000;
    }

    printf("Before\n");
    print_vehicles(vehicles, N_VEHICLES);
    printf("\n");

    // sort by serial number
    qsort(vehicles, N_VEHICLES, sizeof(struct Vehicle *), cmp_serialnumber);
    printf("Sorted by serial number\n");
    print_vehicles(vehicles, N_VEHICLES);
    printf("\n");

    // sort by manufacturer
    qsort(vehicles, N_VEHICLES, sizeof(struct Vehicle *), cmp_manufacturer);
    printf("Sorted by manufacturer\n");
    print_vehicles(vehicles, N_VEHICLES);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . you helped me alot .

Comment: It isn't a good idea to use qsort together with pointer-to-pointer lookup tables. It will only shallow-copy the pointers, not the actual data. So if before calling qsort you have a pointer to a certain Vehicle, that pointer will now point at the wrong place. It is better to use actual 2D arrays instead.

Comment: @Lundin: perhaps your point is too subtle for me to grasp but I have not been able to induce the problem. My understanding is that the values in `struct Vehicle **vehicles`, i.e. the pointers to vehicles, will be shuffled without modification and without modification to any referenced data. If you held a _pointer to a pointer_ to a vehicle then you could see a change, but that's not what's going on here (I think), and it's not what you describe (you mention only a "pointer to a certain Vehicle"). Could you please add an answer that shows how to use `qsort()` properly in this case?